# XRDP ubuntu problem

Tags: desktop-environments, remote-desktop, xrdp

I've installed desktop version on my ubuntu VPS from OVH, via [Connecting to Ubuntu using Windows RDP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYe0zo59iT0) (on YouTube).

I'm logged as user via windows RDP, all working fine, I'm on desktop, but when try to install Google Chrome I'm getting this window:
[image]

I tried root password and also logged user password, both doesn't work, what password should I put there?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated on November 1, 2019**

Source and detailed info : http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=14058

Polkit can be the root cause of the issue... please ensure that the following files exists on your /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local-d directory

**45-allow-colord.pkla**

```
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

**46-allow-update-repo.pkla**

```
[Allow Package Management all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

and this should fix your issue

**Initial Comment**

Please always specify version of Operating system... I would guess that you are running ubuntu 18.04.x and you have performed a successful xrdp installation.

As a guest, the polkit will prevent you to perform installation from remote connection... This is why you have this popup and why password fails

As a workaround, you should install the **software through command line** (example sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks)

Another option would be to start the **software center** from command line...Based on your screenshot, you have a gnome session running through you remote desktop connection

try the following command

> **sudo gnome-software**

Provide password

this should start the software center gui and because started with sudo permissions, you should be able to perform your installation

Hope this help

till next time